# python - invalid value encountered in log

Tags: python, numpy, math, cross-entropy

I have the following expression:
`log = np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-y*np.log(a+ 1e-7)-(1-y)*np.log(1-a+ 1e-7)))`

it is giving me the following warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  log = np.sum(np.nan_to_num(-y*np.log(a+ 1e-7)-(1-y)*np.log(1-a+ 1e-7)))
```

I don't understand what might be the invalid value or why am I getting it. Any and every help is appreciated.

**NOTE**: This is a cross-entropy cost function where I added `1e-7` to avoid having zeros inside log. `y` & `a` are numpy arrays and `numpy` is imported as `np`.

Comment: Note that a similar warning is due to `np.log(np.NaN)`. E.g. when working with pandas data frames with missing values.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You probably still have negative values inside the log, which gives nan with real numbers.

`a` and `y` should represent probability between 0 to 1, So you need to check why do you have smaller/larger values there. Adding 1e-7 shows there is something fishy, because `np.log(0)` gives `-inf`, which I think is the value you want.

Comment: I think adding the 1e-7 will prevent division by 0 error?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `math.log()` replacing `numpy.log()`, which could raise error

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.log(0)
-inf
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.3.0'
>>> import math
>>> math.log(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
```

Comment: A minor comment: `math.log()` take one real number as an input while `numpy.log()` can take a list of real as input. Of course, this difference does not matter in OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

`log(x)` where `x<=0` edge cases

```
np.log(0)

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log

-inf
```

```py
np.log(-1)

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log

nan
```